# org.hibernate.Criteria not working properly with Projections.rowCount()

Tags: hibernate, count, criteria, hibernate-criteria

In a certain point of my application I do a count to display the total records for a datatable - a count of contracts by service, in this case - as follows:

```
public int countByServices(ContractFilter filter) {
        Criteria criteria = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate()).createCriteria(ContractServiceDB.class);
        criteria.createAlias("contract", "contract", Criteria.INNER_JOIN);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("contract.status", filter.getStatus().getId()));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("contract.processed"));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("contract.customerId", filter.getCustomerId()));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.in("service", filter.getServices()));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
        return ((Long) criteria.uniqueResult()).intValue();
}
```

Contract and Service have a many-to-many relationship, and ContractServiceDB is the linking entity, as it has its own attributes. the query runs fine for the first time, but when the method is called once again a moment later it throws an exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of br.com.foo.bar.db.entity.ContractServiceDBPK.cdSncode
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field br.com.foo.bar.db.entity.ContractServiceDBPK.cdSncode to java.lang.Long
```

cdSncode is one of the entity's primary keys, as it is embedded. I, of course, have its getter declared:

```
public String getCdSncode() {
        return this.cdSncode;
}
```

And the String to Long conversion line is the return of the countByServices method - oddly, the result is not a Long value anymore, even with the projection set to rowCount. I also tried

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.countDistinct("contract"));
```

which gave me the same exception.

What am I doing wrong? I can provide you more code if necessary. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the same thing works once, but fails later, we can start by inspecting what is changing between these two times. What is changing in this case?

Comment: I'm having the same issue today. If i call a rowCount() over a Criteria without Restrictions, it works fine. When i call it with restrictions, the exception occurs... If you found a solution, please share!

Answer (score 1):

i was having similar problem.

Look's like you're doing a criteria at the Wrong way:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("contract.status", filter.getStatus().getId()));
```

You have to do "contract.status.id" instead.